# How to detect power button event and deny it on windows 7 from laptop

Tags: windows

On windows XP, I can detect event when pushing power button of laptop.
Condition to get APMQUERYSUSPEND event is option of [control panel->power option->system setting->when I press the power button->sleep] must be changed to ‘Sleep’.

```
MainFrm::OnPowerBroadcast(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

{

```
         switch (wParam)

         {

                       case PBT_APMQUERYSUSPEND:

                       // Ask question whether to power off or not

                       // If not, return BROADCAST_QUERY_DENY

                       return BROADCAST_QUERY_DENY;

         }
```

But from windows 7, I don't have any clue to detect the event. 
Based on windows 7, APMQUERYSUSPEND event was removed. Even though I tried SetThreadExecutionState API to block turn-off, it dose not work. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/windows/desktop/aa372716(v=vs.85).aspx

Do you know any idea to catch event when pushing power button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

According to Microsoft's documentation, it is no longer possible to interrupt a sleep event once it has been initiated. There's a very informative presentation on Windows Vista/7 power control [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/b/9/5b97017b-e28a-4bae-ba48-174cf47d23cd/cpa075_wh06.ppt). 
There is still a way to capture the sleep button event. *I'll be using C# syntax here in my example*:

First, call `RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 0, 0x4000, 0x5F)` from user32.dll API to hook the sleep key. Then override your program's `WndProc` method *(depending on what language and environment you're using, there are different ways to do that)* and listen for the hotkey message 312h. As soon as you receive it, call `SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS)`
 from kernel32.dll API to prevent Windows from initiating a sleep event. After some time (if you want your system to be able to sleep again), you can call `SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS)`.

Note that `SetThreadExecutionState` will not have any effect if a sleep procedure has already been initiated, which is why the above is not possible to do for the power button, which cannot be hooked as far as I know **(if anyone actually knows of a way to do that, please let me know!)**. This is also probably why `SetThreadExecutionState` didn't work for you.

The constants are:

```
        ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000,
        ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 1,
        ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = 0x00000040
```

Comment: just curious after almost four year... is it possible now to hook up to the power button?

Comment: Not that I know of, and, considering Windows' power architecture, would likely only be possible with a driver, if at all... I did a more detailed writeup, but it's pretty much more of what's in the answer above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392653/hook-system-power-button-in-windows/18458390#18458390