# Hook system power button in Windows

Tags: winapi

I have a headless computer running a custom service that I want to enable/disable using the power button, rather than having to remotely connect every time. The computer does other things as well, so turning it off is not an option.

Is it possible to hook the system power button under Windows XP & up, such that my program would get the event **before** Windows initiates a powerdown/sleep event (before `PBT_APMQUERYSUSPEND` event get sent out)?

Comment: You won't be able to hook the power button directly. You *might* be able to use [`RegisterPowerSettingNotification()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373196.aspx/html) to detect an attempt to power down and then deny it, but I don't know the relvant GUId for that particular event (or if it even exists). It is easy to prevent shutdown via `SetThreadExecutionState()`, but then power down is blocked so you won't get notifications. You would probably be best off just connecting a mouse/keyboard to the machine and then use a hook to detect button presses on it.

Comment: optin to handle power notification from windows service ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is indeed possible, but it's a bit hackish and requires two completely different implementations depending on the Windows version. For both methods, you need to set your power button to put the computer to sleep in your power options.

**Windows XP and below:**

You need to overwrite your program's main window's `WndProc` function. On IDEs that don't support this natively, this can be done using `SetWindowLong` in user32 API. In your custom `WndProc` function, listen for a `WM_POWERBROADCAST (0x218)` message. If you receive a message with wParam of `PBT_APMQUERYSUSPEND (0x0)`, call your wanted function and then return `BROADCAST_QUERY_DENY (0x424D5144)` instead of calling the base `WndProc` function. Example code:

```
//At program start
//GWL_WNDPROC = -4
oldWndProc = SetWindowLong(this.hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, &MyWndProc)

//In MyWndProc(hWnd, wMsg, wParam, lParam)
//WM_POWERBROADCAST = 0x218
//PBT_APMQUERYSUSPEND = 0x0
//BROADCAST_QUERY_DENY = 0x424D5144
if wMsg = WM_POWERBROADCAST && wParam = PBT_APMQUERYSUSPEND (
    //CALL YOUR FUNCTION HERE!
    return BROADCAST_QUERY_DENY
)
return CallWindowProc(oldWndProc, hWnd, wMsg, wParam, lParam)

//Before exiting
SetWindowLong(Me.hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, oldWndProc)
```

**Windows Vista & up:** *(thanks to Remy Lebeau for setting me on the right track)*

You need to override `WndProc` like for XP, but also call `SetThreadExecutionState` in kernel32 API to disable sleep mode and `RegisterPowerSettingNotification` in user32 API to listen for advanced power notifications. You will be listening, in particular, to the `GUID_SYSTEM_AWAYMODE` notification, which gets sent out when the system was asked to go to sleep but is unable to do so. To easily convert a string to a properly formed `LPCGUID` you can use `UuidFromStringA` in rpcrt4.dll API. Example code:

```
typedef struct UUID{
    int d1, d2, d3, d4
} LPCGUID;

//At program start
//GWL_WNDPROC = -4
//ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000
//ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x1
//ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = 0x40
//GUID_SYSTEM_AWAYMODE = "98a7f580-01f7-48aa-9c0f-44352c29e5C0"
LPCGUID uid;
oldWndProc = SetWindowLong(this.hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, &MyWndProc)
SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS | ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED)
UuidFromStringA(*(GUID_SYSTEM_AWAYMODE), uid)
ps = RegisterPowerSettingNotification(this.hWnd, uid, 0)

//In MyWndProc(hWnd, wMsg, wParam, lParam)
//WM_POWERBROADCAST = 0x218
//PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE = 0x8013
if wMsg = WM_POWERBROADCAST && wParam = PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE (
    //CALL YOUR FUNCTION HERE!
    //You can additionally extract data from the lParam to verify
    //this is the notification you're waiting for (see below)
)
return CallWindowProc(oldWndProc, hWnd, wMsg, wParam, lParam)

//Before exiting
SetWindowLong(Me.hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, oldWndProc)
UnregisterPowerSettingNotification(ps)
```

This method has the side effect of turning off your physical screen (not a problem on a headless machine), and also possibly locking your session. Make sure you disable prompting for password after sleeping to avoid this. There's some additional useful information on `RegisterPowerSettingNotification` available [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/registerpowersettingnotification.html) which shows how to extract information from the `lParam` in your `WndProc` function in case you want additional info on the notification. Have fun ;)

Comment: "On IDEs that don't support [overriding WinProc] natively". IDE's have **nothing** to do with this. Completely nothing. The entirely non-hackish way is to just process `WM_POWERBROADCAST` normally in your normal `WndProc`.

Comment: nice still work with small changes - thx for correct direction

Answer (score 0):

Now you can set the button action turnOff monitor;
(prior set monitor always on - don't turnoff on idle in settings);

In that way, in *wndproc* will come pwrSetting with a GUID:

```
02731015-4510-4526-99e6-e5a17ebd1aea
```

On the app, run and monitor up `data int32 = 1;`

On monitorOff (i.e., and on pwrButton action in our case, turnOff monitor)

```
data int32 = 0
```

Do a reaction on that action;
additionally, based on needs, you can try prevent monitor off or forcing the monitor on again, etc.

Comment: perfect - created small app to restart windows in normal way with power button;

Comment: 'Now' as in what? A newer version of something? If yes, of what? Of Windows? Of something else? Does it need to be enabled by Windows Registry changes or not? What system was it tested on, incl. Windows version, edition, build number, etc. (and other relevant information)?

Comment: why moderator edit other posts - stack go to bad service now;

Comment: it's for windows 10 - first build 10240 from 2015 year; and for version 1709; I think will work same and for 20 - 22 H and for windows 11 too;

Comment: windows XP had on usb and reactOS version in VM - but no time to test - as I remeber from old days XP don't have option to set same but I use it when was student so not sure....

Comment: looks like post creator not interest in that option and not add comments...