# Detect power button push on a laptop

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, power-management

I'm writing Windows service application using WinAPIs and C++, and I'm curious if it's possible to detect when a user pushes the physical power button on the laptop/notebook?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095517/how-can-i-execute-a-function-when-windows-shut-down and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392653/hook-system-power-button-in-windows

Comment: @chris: The power button may be set to send computer to sleep, or hibernate, or "Do nothing" in that matter. As for the second link, what GUID do I need to use for `RegisterPowerSettingNotification`?

Comment: There seems to be a list here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/registerpowersettingnotification.html

Comment: @chris: Thanks, but I don't see how that would apply to my request... am I missing something?

Comment: Both of them ask about the power button. I figured you might find something useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect power button event and deny it on windows 7 from laptop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433874/how-to-detect-power-button-event-and-deny-it-on-windows-7-from-laptop)

Comment: [Hook system power button in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18392653/995714)

Answer (score -1):

Not really. You can change the action to `None` but you won’t get any notification.